# Why does ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration have an extra connection string not in the file?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, app-config, configurationmanager

I'm unit testing my config file for a win forms application.
In the LocalTestRun.testrunconfig I set it to copy the app.config. I've checked the `Environment.CurrentDirectory` while the test was running and the file doesn't have this extra connection string either. This is the test method:

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Configuration_ConnectionStrings_Connect()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        Assert.IsTrue(System.IO.File.Exists("App.Config"));
        var configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap(){ ExeConfigFilename = "App.Config"};

      var config=  ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

       foreach (ConnectionStringSettings connectionString in config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings)
        {
           //Assumes all connections are to Sql server, test must be updated if not
            Assert.AreEqual("System.Data.SqlClient",connectionString.ProviderName,"Test was only designed for SQL clients");
         using (var cn=new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString))
         {
             cn.Open();
             Assert.AreEqual(System.Data.ConnectionState.Open,cn.State);
         }
        }

    }
```

However When I iterate the `config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings` I have an extra configuration string that is not in the file:

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

This isn't and never was an asp.net project.

Here's the config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="HLIT_Ticketing.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="HLIT_Ticketing.Properties.Settings.HomeQConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=******\*****;Initial Catalog=*****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*****;Password=******"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<userSettings>
    <HLIT_Ticketing.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="AssociateRole" serializeAs="String">
            <value>Associate</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="DeveloperRole" serializeAs="String">
            <value>Developer</value>
        </setting>
    </HLIT_Ticketing.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

Where is this extra connection string coming from?

Comment: +1 i've always wondered this, now I know, thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That connection string is defined in the machine-level configuration file, *machine.config*.

If you look at the file `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config`, you will see the following section:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Is there a way to read the app.config in isolation rather than loading the app.config as an xml file?

Comment: No, sorry - it is as marc_s says!

Answer (score 12):

Dave nailed the main answer - upvoted.

But: if you want to get rid of any connection string from the machine.config or any "up-stream" web.configs, you can always use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <clear />
        <add name="HLIT_Ticketing.Properties.Settings.HomeQConnectionString"
             connectionString="Data Source=******\*****;Initial Catalog=*****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*****;Password=******"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

That first `<clear/>` in the connection strings section wipes out any previously present connection strings and starts with a clean slate.

Comment: Is there a way to tell the configuration manager to load only the file I specify for testing?

Comment: I want to test the app's configuration file, not the machine's.

Comment: No, the ASP.NET config system is already a hierarchy from machine.config, your "root" web.config, and any potential "upstream" web.configs. You cannot change that, it's such a fundamental mechanism.

Comment: so... is there a way through the configuration namespace to read only the app.config and not the machine.config? or am I left to use Linq to XML for this testing?

Comment: The .NET config story is as I said - it's **always** the hierarchy from machine.config -> "root" web.config -> your web.config or machine.config -> yourapp.exe.config. You cannot change that (other than reading the XML yourself, or using the <clear/> tags as I mentioned)

Comment: What if the program _isn't_ reading app.config but you want to force it to?